# VS 2010 unable to load references from previous .NET version and unable to change target framework for new projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an in-house proprietary  library developed in .NET 2.0 using VS 2008 . I upgraded to VS 2010 and using the library in a new project based on 4.0. I have added the library as reference but when I am trying to compile I get an error stating that namespace doesn't exists. 
In addition I tried to change the framework to 2.0 for my new project in VS 2010 . Doing this offloads my project.

Comment: The namespace is part of the proprietary api and is exported by  inhouse library and this is not part of  standard framework

Comment: Where are these references stored?  Quote the path name of one of them.

Comment: Remove and re-add the reference. Might help.

Comment: I managed to change my project to use 3.5 and that seems to be working. So I am assuming the issue is using 2.0 compiled library with 4.0 . The path is C:\work\lib\MarketUtility\MarketUtilityLib.dll . I tried adding and removing references but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your 2.0 assembly does not work on 4.0 projects.

You need update your library to 4.0 or create your new project using 3.5 or below.